# Protecting csv files used for plotting visualizations dynamically via PHP

Tags: php, linux, permissions

Before I begin, I must warn you that I'm not much of a web programmer so my methods may seem somewhat roundabout and the terminology I use may be awkward.

Here's the situation. I'm developing a website for users to visualize data.

I have a public php page sitting in `/var/www/thepage/index.php` path (yes, Linux server + apache). This is the main page of the site and is also where users make selections in a form.

Upon form submission, a second php page will be called and this is where the form selections from the first php page are passed to the javascript that creates the visualization. In order for that to happen, **csv files** are first written into this directory using a php script that queries from a MySQL database.

Thing is, I want users to be able to see the visualizations but not be able to download the csv files (unless they are admin). How I allow admin to download the files is to create a protected (**.htaccess**) subdirectory `/var/www/thepage/secure/` which has an index html that runs a **cgi script** once an admin logs in (prompted when a download link is clicked). This script copies the latest files (with dynamic names) from the `/var/www/thepage/` directory and moves them to the `secure/` directory with static filenames. Download links pointing to these files with static names are on the protected index.html. However, if a user looks at the source code of the 2nd php page, they can also download the files as they know the paths and they are not protected.

If remove file permissions, the php script won't be able to read the files either, causing the visualization to fail (I want normal users to be able to see the visualizations). It is also important to have the files because I have a **cgi script** (bash + awk) running a mathematical function on the files which also requires permission

Obscuring the filenames doesn't really work either since the files are written on the fly and the source code of the html page will reveal the obscured csv filenames being written.

How can I get around this problem? I would prefer **not** to have to create sessions and log-ins for normal users, etc...

Comment: for one thing.. generally on the web  what can be seen can be stolen, you can only hope to make it hard to get so that only a few try and less succeed.. for you case maybe you can save the csv files outside the web root, serve them to the second page using a php file that based on a session var makes sure that it is ran only once

Comment: as the files are written using a php script that queries MySQL after the user inputs to the form are submitted, will I still be able to write the files outside of the web root directory? thanks.

Comment: that's a matter of how you assign the permissions on that directory and not of the presence of it in the web root or not.. so yes, you will if you set the permissions the right way..

Comment: Thanks mishu. Say if I were to use a session var, would I still have the same problem even it is only ran once right? Meaning to say, a normal user, who is allowed to see the graphs, will trigger the serving of the file to the 2nd php page. the moment that happens, viewing the source of the page will allow the user to find the URL to download the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously said, it's hard to hide anything on the net, especially if you need to send it to javascript. You could try hacking it a bit, could cost you a bit of performance, but would be a deterrent against people who aren't web savvy... But could also be seen as a challenge by others :)

A rough example would be something like..

```
$csv = fgetcsv("/var/www/thepage/secure/file.csv");

echo "<script type'text/javascript'>";
echo json_encode($csv);
echo "</script>";
```

Bit rusty here, but javascript should interpret the json as an object, that you can use in your code. You could go a step further and break the php array into sections before sending it off, making it harder to know what's going on.

Like I said. It's rough, but it could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would have imagined the best way is to store the files in a secure directory that isn't accessible in a web browser (outside of the web root). You could then show a list of the available files to authenticated users with a download link. When they click the link you could check they are logged in and if so then begin the file download.

[PHP readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) - May help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, the files are used by the javascript to produce the graphs. If I move them to a directory that is secure from the normal user, they won't be accessible by the javascript. I want the normal users to still see the graphs.